# Рациональное построение базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных

Стоит задача в базе сохранять заявки: 
 

**Заявки :**
 - У каждой заявки может быть одна, либо несколько стандартных целей.
 - Одна цель может содержаться в нескольких заявках

**Цели :**
 - У каждой цели может быть несколько стандартных задач
 - Одна задача может содержаться в нескольких целях

**Методы :**
 - У каждой задачи может быть несколько стандартных методов
 - Один метод может входить во множество задач

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я полагаю, что должны быть своего рода словари(таблицы) стандартных целей/задач/методов. Но не могу придумать или понять, как все это свести к одной заявке?

Правильна ли будет такая структура?
[image: Вот так?]

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "свести в одной заявке"?

Comment: на примере "цель" - "задача": у каждой цели есть свойства (как минимум id и, возможно, название), у каждой задачи также есть некоторые свойства (как минимум id и, возможно, название), это уже две таблицы. Чтобы связать "цель" и "задачу" добавляем связь между ними, т.е. третью таблицу "задачи_цели", у которой есть свойства "id_задачи" и "id_цели". Т.е. одна строка в этой таблице - это связь одной цели с одной задачей. Все задачи цели - это все строки с нужным "id_цели", все цели определенной задачи - это все строки с нужным "id_задачи". Аналогично связываем остальное. Так понятно?

Comment: На вскидку не очевидно, что именно пытается реализовать данная структура. Если речь идет о решении проблем, то явно не хватает флага "решено/не-помогло/попробовать/ в таблицах связей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

резюмируя то что предложил @ВОРОН в кометарии к вопросу - 
нужно сделать минимум 7 таблиц, если без 'справочников' и 'шаблонов'.

4 таблицы тех сущностей, которые обзначил автор вопроса - заявки, цели, задачи и методы. В каждой из них кроме своих информационных полей обязательно должно быть поле уникального идентификатора - ключ (например: id int identity) 
3 другие таблицы - это таблицы - связи, в каждой только два поля - ссылки на id целевых таблиц. Т.е. таблица 'Заявки_цели' с полями: 'id_заявки' и 'id_цели'  (названия условные), аналогично другие две таблицы - 'цели_задачи' и 'задачи_методы'.

Ну и тогда например для выборки информации по всей цепочке от заявки до методов включительно нужно будет формировать запрос из предложения from [заявки] и 6 последовательных join с остальными таблицами этой структуры

Comment: Вставил картинку в вопрос. Так должно получиться?

Comment: да, именно это и имелось ввиду.
И совсем необязательно иметь разные диапазоны ID в таблицах разных сущностей. Они независимы и могут (и будут) пересекаться. Это не будет мешать

Comment: Ну и формально  - все стрелки связей - должны быть направлены в данном случае ИЗ таблиц связей

Comment: Хорошо. Попробую реализовать