# Как избавиться от избыточности при проектировании БД?

Tags: база-данных

Не могу сообразить как создать базу данных для хранения объектов и их связей.

Есть таблица, хранящая кучу объектов сети (компьютеры, сервера, и т.д.)

Нужно создать таблицу хранящую связи этих объектов, для того чтобы в дальнейшем делать выборку по существующим связям конкретного объекта.

К примеру:

**а)** компьютер pc01 имеет связь с серверами srv01,srv02 и компьютером pc03;

**б)** сервер srv03 связан с srv01,srv02,pc03;

все эти связи двунаправленные, т.е.

сервер srv01 связан (судя из пункта **а**) с pc01, а также (судя по пункту **б**) с srv03.
Вот и возникает вопрос по созданию таблицы хранящей данные по связям.

Можно конечно создать таблицу с тремя столбцами:
1 - id записи,
2 - источник,
3 - приемник
Но как избавиться от избыточности записей? т.к. все объекты являются и источниками и приемниками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил изображение. Вот как представляется в общем случае. Во второй таблице наглядно видна избыточность. К примеру: pc01 связан с pc02, зачем нам 4-я запись, ведь в 1-й записи видна эта связь?

Comment: Если у Вас чисто практический интерес, то лучше купите блокнот или что-то в это роде в магазине канцелярских товаров. А все эти базы по инветаризации техники - всё туфта.

Comment: normalize учите

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: [Построение базы данных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508755/)

Comment: Оба варианта в принципе жизненны. В одном случае вы храните линк только в одну сторону и при каждом запросе подбираете записи `id1=N or id2=N`. Либо решаете хранить избыточные данные и храните линк в обе стороны (лучше создание обратного линка делать триггерами), тогда выборки проще. А id связи кстати делать не обязательно, в таблицах связи всего 2 поля, оба в первичном ключе - это нормальная практика

Comment: Можно уйти от дублирования, например, помещая в id1 меньший идентификатор, а в id2 больший.
id1=MIN(1,20) id2=MAX(1,20)

Comment: Из длинной таблицы связей можно смело убрать поле id.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов Не надо. Иначе для установления связи в обратном направлении придётся выполнять до двух запросов. А поскольку не известно какое направление прямое, какое обратное, то любая попытка выявить связь может приветси к двум запросам. И проверка условия между ними - удалось ли установить связь с первой попытки? Не так ли?

Comment: Избыточность(если кто-то считает это избыточностью) здесь полезна. См. предыдущий пост. Она будет ненужной и даже вредной, если это будет не просто связь, а связь со смыслом. Не знаю годится ли такое сравнение: в левой колонке id главного компа, в правой id его терминалов. Обратная запись в данном случае будет ошибкой, потому что главный комп. не может быть терминалом своего терминала.

Comment: @Sergey Вы глубочайше заблуждаетесь: SELECT DISTINCT id1 as id, id2 as id FROM LINKS where id1=123 or id2=123;

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов Что Ваш запрос выдаст в результате? Разбирать потом какой комп попал в id1, какой в id2, сравнивать с тем какой мне нужен слева, какой справа. Можно конечно обойтись одним хитрожопым запросом, но потом всё равно какие-то телодвижения требуюся, что бы понять что где.

Comment: Что-что перечень линков, в которых хотя бы одна сторона равна 123. Если мешается loopback, то достаточно дописать в конец ещё одно условие - SELECT DISTINCT id1 as id, id2 as id FROM LINKS where id1=123 or id2=123 AND id <> 123

Comment: SELECT id1, id2 FROM links WHERE id1=123 - вот все связи компа id1, все они в id2. Никаких больше условий. Сразу в работу. Запрос простой как 2 копейки.

Comment: @Sergey простой до тех пор, пока не вносятся правки в данные. Избыточность требует двухкратного количество вставок. О чём вопрошающий сразу и отметил.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов Это смотря как на это посмотреть. Не такая уж проблема вставить две записи. Да и вставляются они раз в пятилетку, а запрашиваются каждый день.

Comment: какая СУБД у вас ?

Answer (score 1):

Да нет там никакой избыточности. В базе связи как ни крути всегда имеют направление. От источника-2 к приёмнику-3. В левой колонке источник, в правой приёмник.

Когда начинаете избавляться от избыточности, тогда начинается подмена понятий - смысл колонок становится переменчивым. В этой записи левая источник, правая приёмник, в следующей записи всё наоборот.
Вместо простого и ясного запроса придумываются какие-то абракадабры: или запросы-абракадабры, или проверки всяких условий при обработке результатов, или то и другое.
Если вдруг устаните набивать однообразный код для базы и решитесь использовать какой-либо популярный фреймвёрк, то знайте - вряд ли кто разделяет такую оптимизацию.
Вы не от избыточности избавляетесь, а от однозначной трактовки смысла колонок.

Проще добавить две записи для связи в обоих направлениях простыми ясными элементарными командами вставки, получить записи простыми ясными элементарными командами запроса с последующей прямоточной безусловной обработкой, чем выдумывать костыли после сомнительной оптимизации.

Колонку id можно только убрать из таблицы связей. Вот и вся избыточность.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо вынести связь в отдельную таблицу. То есть в одной таблице просто объекты, id и свойства, а в другой - связи (пары айдишников, или `id` , `список зависимых id`)

Comment: Так я и пишу, что нужна еще одна таблица. И про пары id тоже написал. Занесу я данные по первому id к множеству других id, а дальше мне надо занести данные по другому id, но этот второй id уже есть в записях к первому id.

Answer (score 0):

Таблица связывания:

```
CREATE TABLE Links (
      id1 int,
      id2 int, 
      FOREIGN KEY (id1) REFERENCES [[data_table]] (id), 
      FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES [[data_table]] (id),  
      UNIQUE (id1, id2) )
```

Вставка:

```
Insert INTO LINKS VALUES (min(123,321), max (123,321);
```

Чтение:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1 as id, id2 as id FROM Links where id1=123 or id2=123 AND id <> 123
```

Comment: А что действительно можно вернуть два поля с одинаковым именем? А вот это вот id2=123 AND id<>123 с подменой id2 as id плавно превращается в id=123 AND id<>123. Равно и не равно одновременно o_O

Comment: Ещё как можно.  Выборка ведётся по условию или для id1 | id2. Далее эти значения группируются в столбце, названном id. А из этого столбца выкидываются дубликаты id <> x

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто решил оставаться не разумным

```
CREATE TABLE comp_links (
    comp1_id int NOT NULL,
    comp2_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (comp1_id, comp2_id),
    FOREIGN KEY ...
    FOREIGN KEY ...
    CHECK (comp1_id < comp2_id) -- чтобы гарантировать только одну запись 
                                -- для одной и той же пары компьютеров
)
```

За счёт CHECK не надо беспокоится, что в базу по какой-либо причине попадёт обратная связь, от которой потом пришлось бы как-то избавляться, чтобы избежать дубля. Кроме того недопустим "самотык" (comp1_id = comp2_id).

Вставка

```
INSERT INTO comp_links (comp1_id, comp2_id) VALUES (min, max)
```

Получить связи компа comp_id = 123

```
SELECT comp2_id FROM comp_links WHERE comp1_id = 123 -- записи где комп источник
UNION                                                -- объединить с
SELECT comp1_id FROM comp_links WHERE comp2_id = 123 -- записями где комп приёмник
```

Comment: Надо не забыть индекс по `comp2_id`... Хотя это уже от конкретной СУБД зависит.